# perl PDF text coordinates

Tags: perl, pdf

this a simple hello world test script in perl to generate a PDF file :

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use PDF::API2;

# Create a blank PDF file
$pdf = PDF::API2->new();

# Add a blank page
$page = $pdf->page();

# Set the page size
$page->mediabox('A4');

# Add a built-in font to the PDF
$font = $pdf->corefont('Helvetica-Bold');

# Add some text to the page
$text = $page->text();
$text->font($font, 20);
$text->translate(72, 28); # 1inch, 1cm
$text->text('Hello World!');

# Save the PDF
$pdf->saveas('test.pdf');
```

I was expecting the bottom of my text to be 1cm above the page bottom but it's not (on the other hand, the x position is correctly at 1 inch from the left of the page).

Measuring on the printed page shows that 1cm is at the center of the text (more or less). Does this mean the y-positioning of an object is from its vertical middle ?

Thanks

Comment: That's seems like something you could figure out on your own with some experimentation

Comment: don't kill too many trees in the process...

Comment: Most likely the letter base line is the answer, that at least is true for pdfs in general.

Comment: How accurate is your printer?

Comment: My printer is not per say a killer... Samsung M2070...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a couple of key objects copied and pasted from the output PDF, once uncompressed:

the Page object:

```
5 0 obj
<< /Type /Page /Contents [ 7 0 R ] /MediaBox [ 0 0 595 842 ] /Parent 2 0 R
   /Resources << /Font << /HeBoCBA~1438376482 6 0 R >> /ProcSet
   [/PDF /Text /ImageB /ImageC /ImageI ] >> >>
endobj
```

The page content:

```
7 0 obj
<< /Length 77 >>
stream
BT  /HeBoCBA~1438376482 20 Tf 1 0 0 1 72 28 Tm [ (Hello World!) ] TJ  ET
endstream
endobj
```

The Media Box is `[0 0 595 842]`, which is A4.

The instruction `1 0 0 1 72 28 Tm` (set text matrix) is setting `Tx` to 72 and `Ty` to 28.

So looking at the PDF, it does seem to be correctly setting the page size to `A4` and positioning text from its baseline rather than its center.

*Update:*
Here's a screen shot showing the appearance of `Hello World!` on the PDF in Adobe Reader, using the measuring tools at a zoom of 300%.

[image]

Comment: OK thanks so how do you explain the 1cm y is located at the center of the text while the x is correctly at 1 inch ? I tried Tx 72 AND ty 72 and again the 1 inch y is at the center of the text... strange. when trying tx 0 and Ty 0, I correctly have my text starting horizontally and vertically at the bottom left corner of the page !

Comment: Just quickly: Measuring of hard-copy is not recommended. Acrobat Reader has some pretty good built-in measuring tools. `Zoom` & `Edit >> Analysis >> Measuring Tools` are your friends, along with `Edit >> Preferences >> Measuring`.

Comment: According to Reader distance tool, my text seems correctly positioned on the page. I guess I have to blame my printer ... crazy it is perfectly precise for x and not at all for y coordinate

Comment: Might be something in your printer settings that can help. Most likely it's scaling and not respecting the media box setting.

Comment: I basically measured directly on the hard copy because I was trying to automize barcodes printing on labels (A4 sheets). Checking my printer settings ( which I never changed) I noticed that the number of lines per inch is set to 6. Does it seem correct?

Comment: I don't think that setting would explain the variation depending obn exactly where you put the text. Not knowing the driver, I was more thinking of along the lines of something that can be turned off like `autocropping` or `scale-to-fit`. Just being hopeful maybe.

Comment: I asked 2 friends to print this pdf file : https://www.dropbox.com/s/zo5oxsv98662k0i/test1.pdf?dl=0. One of them has a top business printer and none of them has the square printed 1inch from bottom and left. I checked my printer settings again and I see no obvious setting explaining the offset.